# Plotting in Matlab as the parameter value is changed

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a simple function against time. The code is below. The issue is when I change the parameter `c` to be 1.3 the plot does not get drawn to the whole time span that I have specified, where as if I use `c` to be 3.4 it draws in the whole time span.

What is it that I am doing wrong that when `c=1.3` the plot stops at x=1298 (I want it to be drawn all the way up to 2000)? Is it an issue with the function that I use to generate the values?

```
time=0:2000;
a=10^7;
b=1000;
c=log(2)/(3.4-2.1);
d=log(2)/((6.92)*24);
values=(a*b*exp((c-d).*time))./((a-b)+b*exp(c.*time));

figure
plot(time,values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `values` variable in the workspace. 
You will see that from the index 1300, it gets the `Inf` or `NaN` value. These values cannot be plotted. I guess the denominator gets 0 at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code for `1.3`

When you put `1.3` , then `c` get negative.

```
c = 
   -0.8664
```

Then all the values in final formula get a very close number to zero.